# Fiddle works - actual web page does not - <code> <pre>

Tags: javascript, html, css

http://jsfiddle.net/tovic/AbpRD/

Fiddle has JavaScript, HTML, CSS
When code is placed in web page and rendered it does not
behave as the fiddle does (i.e. no line numbers)

```
(function () {
    var pre = document.getElementsByTagName('pre'),
    pl = pre.length;
    for (var i = 0; i < pl; i++) {
        pre[i].innerHTML = '<span class="line-number"></span>' + pre[i].innerHTML + '<span class="cl"></span>';
        var num = pre[i].innerHTML.split(/\n/).length;
        for (var j = 0; j < num; j++) {
            var line_num = pre[i].getElementsByTagName('span')[0];
            line_num.innerHTML += '<span>' + (j + 1) + '</span>';
        }
    }
})();
```

Comment: Any console errors? Are you sure your JavaScript is being executed?

Comment: It does work the same, and I put the js code right before the body close tag

Comment: did you placed your code in window.onload? Becasue probably your code is executed before DOM is loaded

Comment: Does the script get called at all? If you put an `alert` in the script, does it show? Anyway, can you provide an URL where it doesn't work?